# How to deep format all datetime attributes in ruby object?

Tags: ruby, datetime, ruby-grape

I am building a REST API in Ruby using [Grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape).

My frontend is written in [AnguarJS](https://github.com/angular/angular.js) and the default datetime serialization made by Grape is not correctly being understood by [angulars' date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date). So my idea is to format all the datetime attributes in ruby before sending it.

What is the best approach ?

- Is there a generic [Time](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html)  serialization in Grape that I can use ?
- If not, is it feasible to perform a deep lookup in a ruby list or map, find all Time instances, and replace them by a formatted string ?

My current solution below is tightly coupled for one attribute, but I would like to extend this formatting to all Time instantes.

```
    result_json.each do | x |
      x[:date] = x[:date].strftime("%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S")
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Grape Entity then you can extend the **ApiHelper** to include a new formatter. For example:

```
module ApiHelpers
  extend Grape::API::Helpers

  Grape::Entity.format_with :iso8601 do |date|
    date.iso8601 if date
  end
end
```

Once you have done it, you can use it in your Entities like this:

```
module Entities
  class MyModel < Grape::Entity
    expose :updated_at, format_with: :iso8601
  end

  class AnotherModel < Grape::Entity
    expose :created_at, format_with: :iso8601
  end
end
```

I believe it's the best way to tackle this problem because you shouldn't change the Time class just to solve a problem in your View layer. Using Grape Entity is a good practice too. You should always shield your API from possible changes in your Models. Also, remember that what you expose through a Rest API are "Resources" and not Models. In fact, a resource can even be a combination of multiple Models and Entities allow you to define a Resource and reuse it wherever you need it. Using entities, you can exclude fields, create fields that are a combination of others fields. It gives you flexibility.